# How to get fields from the child table in the result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have join between two tables. Instruments is the parent table and Statuses are the child table. I am looking only to retrieve those instruments having the inst_status = 'Active' in the child Statuses table.

```
i = Instrument.joins(:statuses).where("statuses.inst_status='Active'")
```

The resulted query generated is:

```
SELECT "instruments".* FROM "instruments" INNER JOIN "statuses" ON "statuses"."instrument_id" = "instruments"."id" WHERE (statuses.inst_status='Active')
```

Which is OK it is returning only 55 instruments which are Active.
However, how can I get the fields from the Statuses (child) table in the result set along with the fields from the (parent) Instruments table?

Comment: Is this an eager load question?

Comment: OK , I found some double quotes missing: here is the statement I run: i = Instrument.joins(:statuses).where("statuses.inst_status='Active'").select("instruments.*", "statuses.*")    However now I cannot execute count or first on the result set. Statements like i.count or i.first are failing. Also i[0] does not have the statuses fields in the result set.

Comment: I renounced to get all the fields, I want only the id from the parent table and the inst_status form the child table. Here is the statement: i = Instrument.joins(:statuses).where("statuses.inst_status='Active'").select("instruments.id", "statuses.inst_status")

Comment: Which generates the SQL: SELECT instruments.id, statuses.inst_status FROM "instruments" INNER JOIN "statuses" ON "statuses"."instrument_id" = "instruments"."id" WHERE (statuses.inst_status='Active')

Comment: do `i[0].attributes`, you will see all the columns from both tables..

Comment: But in the result set I am getting only the parent table field, the child table field inst_status is misising:

Comment: 2.1.5 :113 > i[0]
 => #<Instrument id: 3052>

Comment: got it2.1.5 :114 > i[0].attributes
 => {"id"=>3052, "inst_status"=>"Active"} 
2.1.5 :115 > i[0].id
 => 3052 
2.1.5 :116 > i[0].inst_status
 => "Active"

Comment: @L.D that's wrapped inside. You just do `i[0].attributes`

Comment: OK, i.count does not work anymore with the join. But i[0], i.first works and I can get also the wrapped inside fields. Also i[0].attributes and i[0].attributes works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, You have to use [`select`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields) method for this :

```
Instrument.joins(:statuses)
          .where("statuses.inst_status='Active'")
          .select("inst‌​ruments.*, statuses.*")
```

Comment: Does not work. The statements work without select. Once select is added no query is generated the prompt is returned like for an incomplete statement.

Comment: @L.D Just delete your _doesn't comment.._ for future readers. :D